# Where to find information about used algorithms behind blender functions?

Tags: mesh

Currently I am interested in fixing holes in meshes. Unfortunately I could not find any information or reference to the algorithms that are used in Blender.
It would be great if somebody could point me into the right direction.

Kind regards,
Leszek

Comment: A starting point https://www.blender.org/get-involved/developers/ . But your question should be more specific about the functions or data structures you're looking for.